# Creating MySQL OLEDB connection string

Tags: mysql, oledb, oledbconnection

I am trying to create a connection to a MySQL database from a call center scripting software called Amtelco Intelligent Series via OLEDB.

The MySQL server runs on an Ubuntu VM that I have terminal access to but I don't know anything about Linux. There is a Python program that connects to this MySQL server with the following string:

```
MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="", db="[dbName]", host="[serverIP]")
```

Is there any way I can glean an OLEDB connection string from this information? Is it even a given that this MySQL server runs an OLEDB provider?